# Combining 2 itertools product lists for a larger combination to find all combinations

Tags: python, combinations, product, python-itertools

Basically I am trying to reduce the number of combinations using itertools.product but get all combinations from the 4 elements using 2 lists.

I am able to create the 2 separate element lists of combinations but I cannot figure out how to combine the 2 list getting all combinations of them.

```
import itertools
pos_vars = ('a', 'b')
pos_num = (1, 0.5, 0)
neg_vars = ('c', 'd')
neg_num = (-1, -0.5, 0)
pos = [list(zip(pos_vars, p)) for p in itertools.product(pos_num, repeat=2)]
print(pos)
[[('a', 1), ('b', 1)], [('a', 1), ('b', 0.5)], [('a', 1), ('b', 0)], [('a', 0.5), ('b', 1)], [('a', 0.5), ('b', 0.5)], [('a', 0.5), ('b', 0)], [('a', 0), ('b', 1)], [('a', 0), ('b', 0.5)], [('a', 0), ('b', 0)]]

neg = [list(zip(neg_vars, n)) for n in itertools.product(neg_num, repeat=2)]
print(neg)
[[('c', -1), ('d', -1)], [('c', -1), ('d', -0.5)], [('c', -1), ('d', 0)], [('c', -0.5), ('d', -1)], [('c', -0.5), ('d', -0.5)], [('c', -0.5), ('d', 0)], [('c', 0), ('d', -1)], [('c', 0), ('d', -0.5)], [('c', 0), ('d', 0)]]
```

The combined list from both lists should look something like:
`[[('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', -1), ('d', -1)], [('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', -1), ('d', -0.5)], etc.]`

I am able to get the full range but am basically doubling the computations which I am trying to avoid using the below code:

```
full_var = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
full_num = (-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1)
full = [list(zip(full_var, f)) for f in itertools.product(full_num, repeat=4)]
```

Thanks in advance!

Update - I was able to get my 81 combinations. Not the most efficient coding but it works and can be improved upon.

```
pos_a_var = ('a')
pos_b_var = ('b')
neg_c_var = ('c')
neg_d_var = ('d')
pos_num = (1, 0.5, 0)
neg_num = (-1, -0.5, 0)
pos_a = list(itertools.product(pos_a_var, pos_num))
pos_b = list(itertools.product(pos_b_var, pos_num))
neg_c = list(itertools.product(neg_c_var, neg_num))
neg_d = list(itertools.product(neg_d_var, neg_num))
comb_list = [pos_a, pos_b, neg_c, neg_d]
all_combinations = list(itertools.product(*comb_list))
len(all_combinations)
81
```

Still working on making this code a bit cleaner.

Comment: Did you time both approaches and see if one of them is faster/slower than the other?

Comment: But are you sure that when you combine pos and neg to make your final output, you will end up having more or less the same number of combinations

Comment: I should end up with 3^4 = 81 combinations. Full is 5^4 = 625 combinations

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
print([x + y for x, y in zip(pos, neg)])
```

Output:

```
[[('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', -1), ('d', -1)], [('a', 1), ('b', 0.5), ('c', -1), ('d', -0.5)], [('a', 1), ('b', 0), ('c', -1), ('d', 0)], [('a', 0.5), ('b', 1), ('c', -0.5), ('d', -1)], [('a', 0.5), ('b', 0.5), ('c', -0.5), ('d', -0.5)], [('a', 0.5), ('b', 0), ('c', -0.5), ('d', 0)], [('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 0), ('d', -1)], [('a', 0), ('b', 0.5), ('c', 0), ('d', -0.5)], [('a', 0), ('b', 0), ('c', 0), ('d', 0)]]
```

Comment: Wondering why `list(map(operator.add, zip(pos,neg)))` is not working for this case

Comment: Then how come `for x,y in zip(pos,neg): print(operator.add(x,y))` works

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Oh yeah, because in `map` you don't iterate like `x, y` just `x`, and also `zip` gives value with type of `tuple`, and one tuple

Comment: You are right, `list(map(lambda x:x[0]+x[1], zip(pos,neg)))` works

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh My mistake. It was posted with U9-Forward. I'll make the correction.

Comment: @U9-Forward Your solution does not provide all combinations from a, b, c, d together. Your adding the combinations of (a, b) and (c,d) together which is not the same.